# issue with service stack protein tracker tutorial (won't launch meta data)

Tags: servicestack

issue with service stack protein tracker tutorial (won't launch meta data)

My main issues is when I launch the site and go to /metadata nothing shows up

Here is the new entry in the web config

```
  <system.webServer> 
    <handlers> 
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" /> 
    </handlers> 
  </system.webServer>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, still trying to figure this out. Looks like I was wrong about the application_start not getting called. Now that is being called. hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue is the lack of IIS. :(

Changed the config to this and now I see the meta data

```
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
```

Excited to get on to the next part of the tutorial :)